# Slow execution of request for searching nearest street to GPS point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, nearest-neighbor

I use OSM data. I need to find nearest street for GPS point. I wrote next SQL query:

```
SELECT 
     osm_id, 
     name,  
     ST_DISTANCE(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(37.72308, 55.47957), 4326), true) as dist 
FROM 
     roads 
WHERE 
     ST_DWithin(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(37.72308, 55.47957), 4326), 1) ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1;
```

But it's execution is very slow. It's take 7.5 seconds for not big territory. Table structure is next:

```
newdb=# \d roads
                                   Table "public.roads"
  Column  |           Type            |                     Modifiers                      
----------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                   | not null default nextval('roads_id_seq'::regclass)
 osm_id   | bigint                    | 
 type     | character varying         | 
 name     | character varying         | 
 tunnel   | smallint                  | 
 bridge   | smallint                  | 
 oneway   | smallint                  | 
 ref      | character varying         | 
 z_order  | integer                   | 
 access   | character varying         | 
 service  | character varying         | 
 class    | character varying         | 
 geometry | geometry(LineString,4326) | 
Indexes:
    "roads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "roads_geography" gist (geometry)
    "roads_geom" gist (geometry)
```

is there any way to increase speed of the query?

PostGIS 2.2
PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your query calculates the distance using ST_DISTANCE from your point to every road in a 1° distance (~ 100 km). This is slow!

You can instead use the [<-> operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) which makes use of indexes:

```
SELECT
  osm_id, 
  name,
  ST_DISTANCE(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(37.72308, 55.47957), 4326), true) as dist 
FROM roads
ORDER BY geometry <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(37.72308, 55.47957), 4326)
LIMIT 1;
```

From the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html):

> The <-> operator returns the 2D distance between two geometries. Used in the "ORDER BY" clause provides index-assisted nearest-neighbor result sets.

Comment: thanks! Should I write `geometry::geography` or `geometry` is enough?

Comment: geometry is enough, otherwise you would need add ::geography also to your point to compare them.